# How to show custom post type on homepage and in categories

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

**Details**
Wordpress Version: 3.4
Theme Deadline Version 1.2
Site URL: [littlenomads](http://www.littlenomads.com)

Plugin being used to create the Custom Posts Types

1.[Types Plugin – Custom Post Types, Taxonomies and Custom Fields](http://wp-types.com/home/types-manage-post-types-taxonomy-and-custom-fields/)
 2. [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/)

**Problem:** I have created a custom post type called "Accommodation" which is working fine. However I can't seem to get the custom post types  to show up with the categories it shares and on the home page under one of my blocks.

This piece of code works on the block, however it only pullsthe custom post type and not the other posts that are also tagged under "pictures".

```
$tz_recent_posts = new WP_Query(); $tz_recent_posts->query('offset=1&post_type=Accommodation,page,post&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=' . $tz_recent_number . '');
```

Any assistance that anyone can provide is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your child themes functions file:

```
function wpsites_add_cpt_home($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
  $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'accommodation' ) );
    }
  }

add_action('pre_get_posts','wpsites_add_cpt_home');
```

You could also add

```
category__in => array()
```

Source [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 0):

`post_type` is case-sensitive, and should be all lower case.  Try changing `Accommodation` to `accommodation`, see what happens.  You might also consider converting your query to arguments to pass to `WP_Query()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

SickHippie might be right about trying lower-case but another error in your query is the use of "`caller_get_posts`" parameter. This has been [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters) since version 3.1. You should use `ignore_sticky_posts` instead.